# What options are there for creating universally accessible javascript functions (on the client side) in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I'm starting out with Meteor at the moment.  As with any JS based project, it helps to have a little algorithm library somewhere that contains handy basic functions to invoke throughout the project code.

I'm still getting my head around the app infrastructure, so I am wondering two things about making functions universally accessible across the client side:
1) Where should the functions go?
2) What framework functionality should I use (or is used automatically) to make them available throughout the project?

Comment: You may want to also checkout free chapters of the Discover Meteor html book. It *really* helped clear up my confusion with folder hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a "client" folder in your Meteor root application directory.
Inside it, create a "js" directory, and simply put your javascripts files in it.
Then declare your global vars and functions this way :

```
myVar=VALUE;
myFunction=function(arguments){...};
```

Using the classic syntax (var myVar=VALUE;) will cause your symbols to be only local to the source file.
In your "js" folder, you can play with the order in which scripts are loaded (read the docs for futher details), but basically, everything inside a "lib" folder gets loaded first, and inside folders, files are loaded using filename alphabetical order.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It works great.  When I use function syntax like this though, it doesn't work: function test(){console.log("test");}  Any ideas why?

Comment: Have you tried using the syntax I suggested ? ie
test=function(){console.logt("test");};

Comment: Yes, as I said, your syntax does work.  I was just wondering why the syntax actually makes a difference (if perchance you know).

Comment: @Pat I believe it's because each file now has variable scope. so the example code would have to be written as ` test = function(){console.log("test");} ` . I think you can also use this.test to globalize it (on both client and server).